# No option to create Animation Node editor

Tags: interface, animation-nodes

In Blender versions 2.82a/2.83/2.90 I do not have option to create Animation Node Editor, all other 8 general editors (3D Viewport to Movie Clip) are listed (as well as usual Animation, Scripting and Data)

This is after crash using Animation Node Editor (undeleting a Node) but even though have completing removed the Blender directory and ".../config/userpref.blend" and clean reinstall the Animation Node Editor is not listed, what other files do I need to remove?

I can not report bug/ask for help at developer.blender.org as made a mistake with my email address!

This is under 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you actually re-activate the add-on after reinstalling blender ?

Comment: Animation nodes is an addon. Did you enable it?

Comment: Ooops, forgot that is was add-on. Strange that is was unavailable after the crash but before reinstall... never mind - thanks!